# how to do cross app automation testing for android

Tags: android, testing, automation

lots of apps now need to interact with other apps. i'll give some examples:

take picture by calling system camera

open url like http://www.shihuangzhilu.com in a browser

android instruments can only test one app per time. can we do automation testing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can test across applications, see monkeyrunner:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html

(not to be confused with Monkey, another android tool)

Comment: i just  use chimchat to make it . python is not that stable

Answer (score 2):

You can't explicit definitely not using the current testing framework of android.
What you can do is use robotium, and then check if you have gotten the values back, and that you are no longer within your application/activity, that's the only way i can think of.